# Where to get offline documentation/descriptions of individual sysctl kernel tunable parameters?

Tags: kernel, documentation, sysctl, kernel-parameters, tuning

The `NOTES` section of `$ man 5 sysctl.conf` states: `The description of individual parameters can be found in the kernel documentation.`

But is there a way for me to find this kernel documentation offline? Is it a package that I'd need to install?

For example, I came across the `kernel.panic` parameter, which on my system is set to 0 by default. Looking it up online [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt), it's described to be:

```
panic:

The value in this file represents the number of seconds the kernel
waits before rebooting on a panic. When you use the software watchdog,
the recommended setting is 60.
```

But there is no reasonable way I'd guessed that the `0` there referred to 0 seconds till auto reboot without searching it up online.

Comment: What's your distro? On Debian you'd need the `linux-doc` package and the document would be `/usr/share/doc/linux-doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt.gz`.

Comment: 0 doesn't mean reboot immediately, BTW: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/564735/70524

Comment: @Freddy pretty much exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I'm looking for the EL-family actually, and a quick search revealed that the `kernel-doc` package is what I need.

Comment: @muru thanks for the link, didn't know about `man 5 proc`, which looks also helpful for my purposes. And that was indeed my second guess on what the `0` value did lol. (sort of like how an ipv4 of `0.0.0.0` can either mean no valid address or all valid addresses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But is there a way for me to find this kernel documentation offline? Is it a package that I'd need to install?

Yes, most distributions provide the kernel documentation for their kernel in a package. On Debian, this is `linux-doc`, which is a meta-package pulling in the default kernel’s documentation for whichever release you’re using (version-specific packages are available too, *e.g. `linux-doc-4.19`). On RHEL, CentOS etc. it’s `kernel-doc`.

You’ll find the file you’re looking for in this case in `/usr/share/doc/kernel-doc-*/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt` on RHEL. In newer versions the file has been converted to ReSTructured text and can be found in `.../Documentation/admin-guide/sysctl/kernel.rst` (which is also where you can find [the current kernel `sysctl` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/kernel.html) on the kernel web site).

Checking the packaged version gives you a better chance to get the documentation matching your running kernel; in some cases though the current documentation is more accurate, even for older kernels, and this is the case here — I improved the documentation following [Linux Kernel.org misleading about kernel panic /proc/sys/kernel/panic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/564735/86440), and that ended up in version 5.7 of the kernel.