# Why don't the addresses in `/boot/System.map-*` and `/proc/kallsyms` match?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, kernel

Consider the output of `/boot/System.map-5.8.0-50-generic` and `/proc/kallsyms` on Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla):

```
$ sudo cat /boot/System.map-5.8.0-50-generic | grep sys_call_table
ffffffff820002e0 D sys_call_table
ffffffff82001360 D ia32_sys_call_table
ffffffff82002120 D x32_sys_call_table
$ sudo cat /proc/kallsyms | grep sys_call_table
ffffffff978002e0 D sys_call_table
ffffffff97801360 D ia32_sys_call_table
ffffffff97802120 D x32_sys_call_table
```

**AFAIK, these files should contain the current load addresses of kernel symbols, so why don't they match?**

Is it because only `/proc/kallsyms` is affected by KASLR? If so, how can I verify whether KASLR is enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is [caused by KASLR](https://bneuburg.github.io/volatility/kaslr/2017/04/26/KASLR1.html). Note that all addresses are offset by the same amount. The kernel doesn’t know about `System.map` so it doesn’t update it.

I’m not aware of any way of detecting whether KASLR is enabled from userspace at runtime, short of comparing `/proc/kallsyms` and `System.map`, or possibly causing a panic on x86 (the kernel dumps its offset on panic there).

Comment: Panics are fatal. `System.map` contains the symbol addresses as determined by `nm` from the kernel image; without KASLR they do end up being the addresses in virtual memory, yes.

Comment: Sorry, yes, “fatal” means the system is no longer usable (and [Linux can be configured to reboot automatically after a panic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/564749/86440)), so leaking the offset doesn’t reduce the system’s security.

Comment: The kernel does operate in a virtual address space...

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry, I was confused. Thought for a second the kernel only utilizes virtual memory spaces for user-space processes.